# ionic app not scrolling on sidemenu + tab bar UI Pattern combination

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I followed last example of [this blog entry](http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-framework-tutorial-4-mixing-ui-patterns/2/) and I'm not being able to scroll my app.

To test this example I used just created some divs (with cards on it), those cards are loaded with dynamic data.

My home.html file looks like:

```html
<ion-view>
    <ion-tabs>
      <ion-tab>
       <ion-content>
        <div>
        <!-- several divs goes here -->
```

I can't be able to figure why content is not scrolling. I also tried with solution of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787572/ionic-vertical-scrolling-not-working-in-tabbed-content/30795893#30795893) without any luck.

Hope you can help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the setup (device, browser) you test with? Can you provide a jsfiddle/codepen/... with a minimal case as an example of your issue (don't forget CSS!)? Did you read the Ionic docs on [ionContent](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent/) and the available scroll options?

Comment: Another remark: Do you call `.resize()` with `$ionicScrollDelegate` after the content has been added? This might be necessary as you work with "dynamic" data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line..

```
<ion-content scroll="true">
```

if you hide scrolling then use..

```
<ion-content scroll="false">
```